# Checking a MacBook for hard disk for errors when it multi-boots into Windows and macOS

Tags: hard-drive, boot, mac, liveusb

I haven't dealt with macs, but was asked for a help with a MacBook being super slow. Looks like a MacBook is ‎2008-2009 year edition.

It has two OS's installed on it - Windows and macOS. I was able to load macOS once, but that was basically it - system froze after that. Couldn't load it again. When turning MacBook on and then choosing which OS to use, sometimes it doesn't show the Windows icon. And even when showing the icon - not able to load windows and pops up the msg "windows not detected".

From a flash drive I was able to load USB-live Linux, but couldn't mount devices. Fsck scan revealed bunch of errors on a disc, but unable to correct them all. But at least after scanning and error correction I was able to mount device. System saw 3 devices: main, recovery and one with unknown FS Windowsdata. Based on everything said above I assume the problem is with the hard drive.

Tried some bootable flash-drives with Hirens Boot CD and Victoria add MHDD, but the MacBook doesn't see my any of these flash drives as bootable even though before I was able to run live image Linux from it as I said earlier, and loaded desktop from that flash drives. And by the way - not able to insert a CD via CD drive on this MacBook, feels like something stuck in there.

So, questions: How can I check hard disk for bad sectors?

Comment: A few points... 1) I presume you mean macOS not iOS. 2) did you run fsck_hfs? If not, you may have caused more issues than you cured. 3) Mac will only boot from GUID volumes, not MBR. 4) Best guess right now would be to dd as much info off the drive as you can before making any further attempts to 'fix' it.

Comment: I did run fsch, but from linux fsck detect hfs Fs and redirect to fsck automatic. I nead test HD for hardware bad sectors. Macbook not contaited valuable information.
I can't create live-USB with FreeDOS or any OS to run Victoria, MHDD e.t.c.
Perhaps you did not hear about this soft for testing HDD?